# JAVA: Double.parseDouble + Double.parseDouble = String

Tags: java, android

I have this problem in my program:
When I do this:

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(zero);
double b = Double.parseDouble(data);
double c = a+b;
String d = Double.toString(c);
```

It returns me a `String`. For example, I have 0.0 in `a` and 4.0 in `b` and it returns `0.04.0`.

Can someone explain to me why and what I should do instead?

EDITED: Here is my code:

```
private void WriteMedia(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("writemedia.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        String zero;
        if(ReadMedia().isEmpty() == true)
        {
            zero = "0.0";
            outputStreamWriter.write(zero);
        }
        else {zero = ReadMedia();}
        double a = Double.parseDouble(zero);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(data);
        double c = a+b;
        String d = Double.toString(c);
        outputStreamWriter.write(d);

        outputStreamWriter.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}


private String ReadMedia() {


    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("writemedia.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("estrela.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        WriteMedia(data);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}


private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("estrela.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }
    WriteMedia(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

The data is a ratingbar, zero is "0" when I start the app and it should save the rating bar to "increment"(don't know the english word). I thought it would be easy but since is like a bug just for me i'll put the tag android studio.

Here is where I call the method:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rating = ratingbar.getRating();
            writeToFile(Double.toString(rating));

            writeMyArray(Double.parseDouble(readFromFile()));
            writeMyArray(ratingbar.getRating());
            button.setText(getText(R.string.obrigado) + "!" + readFromFile() + " " + media(arraydays)  + " " + ReadMedia());

        }
    });
```

It returns me the "0.0" and the ratingbar together, for example: "0.05.0"

Comment: See the return. The calculation gives me a string, putting the two values together like i showed in the question. If you don't understand the question, don't downvote it.

Comment: Then show the code that does what you say... This ain't it

Comment: That is why I ask @mastov. It should not do that, so I came to stackoverflow and what I get is downvotes.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo this doesn't behave as you say...`d = "4.0"` not `"0.04.0"`

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: It **should** not do that and I'm sure it **doesn't**. You have not provided the code that actually relates to your question. You *must* be doing something different.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo, When you post code with a problem, you should give minimum code with which we will be able to reproduce the problem. But as Red has mentioned, the issue is not reproducible. That's why the downvotes.

Comment: @mastov see the code

Comment: `public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
double c = a+b;
String d = Double.toString(c);
    System.out.println(d);
  }
}` spits out 0.4, as expected. Since you claim yours behaves differently, then you should give us more details.

Comment: you print out `zero` in your if (`outputStreamWriter.write(zero); `) and later the result of your calculation --> 0.0[result]

Comment: @griFlo can you explain yourself in other words?

Comment: see the answer of @mastov

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is *not* related to types (other than you guessed) and it is *not* in the code you originally posted.

Instead, you are simply writing *2* numbers to your output stream. The following code writes `0.0`:

```
    if(ReadMedia().isEmpty() == true)
    {
        zero = "0.0";
        outputStreamWriter.write(zero);
    }
```

And, in *addition* to that, the following code writes the result you *actually* want:

```
    double a = Double.parseDouble(zero);
    double b = Double.parseDouble(data);
    double c = a+b;
    String d = Double.toString(c);
    outputStreamWriter.write(d);
```

Comment: but c would be a+b, so changing this to numbers, 1+2 = 3 so c, converted to string(d), would be 3 anyway. If I have the number 3, when I convert to string can't convert to "1"+"2".

Comment: Yes, and the result in `c` is correct! BUT: You are not looking at what is in `c`, you are looking at what is in the output stream. And the output stream contains the "0.0" and afterwards the true result.

Comment: @mastov I didn't take a close look at his updates to the question. Instead I answered something that I assumed that he might be facing with. My bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How can I put a zero in the outputstream then?

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: I'm not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. But I'm guessing that either the first `outputStreamWriter.write(zero);` is superfluous or that the whole second code block should be within the curly brackets of your `else` branch.